# Store procedure sql server con asp.net mvc 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla en sql server llamada Marca, esta contiene cuatro campos:

```
IIDMARCA int, 
NOMBRE varchar, 
DESCRIPCION varchar, 
BHABILITADO int
```

y tengo un procedimiento almacenado que consulta tres de esos cuatro campos

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LISTAR_MARCAS
AS
BEGIN
SELECT IIDMARCA, NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION
FROM Marca
WHERE BHABILITADO = 1
END
```

En mi proyecto asp.net tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en el procedimiento coloco `select * from marca`, en mi vista coloco la columna item.bhabilitado se elimina el problema, pero no estoy interesado en listar todas las columnas, y no sé como solucionar esto, agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar, si se requiere más información estaré pendiente.

esto sería mi controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using prototipo_03.Models;

namespace procedimientos_almacenados.Controllers
{
    public class MarcaController : Controller
    {
        BDPasajeEntities bd = new BDPasajeEntities();
        // GET: Marca
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ListarMarcas();
            return View();
        }

        public void ListarMarcas()
        {
            List<Marca> ListaMarca = new List<Marca>();

            using (bd)
            {
                var ListaMarca3 = bd.SP_LISTAR_MARCAS().ToList();
                foreach (var item in ListaMarca3)
                {
                    var asignar = new Marca
                    {
                        IIDMARCA = item.IIDMARCA,
                        NOMBRE = item.NOMBRE,
                        DESCRIPCION = item.DESCRIPCION,
                    };
                    ListaMarca.Add(asignar);
                }
                ViewBag.ListaMarca = ListaMarca;
            } 
    }
}
```

esta mi vista

```
@using prototipo_03.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    List<Marca> ListaMarca = (List<Marca>)ViewBag.ListaMarca;
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ListaMarca)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.IIDMARCA</td>
            <td>@item.NOMBRE</td>
            <td>@item.DESCRIPCION</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

He tratado de implementar mi propio modelo que llame MarcaCLS para diferenciar a Marca que viene del modelo traido de la base de datos, pero estoy limitado en este tema, que hice de igual manera pero no sé como hacer que trabaje

```
 public partial class Marca
    {
        public int IIDMARCA { get; set; }
        public string NOMBRE { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BHABILITADO { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo que listar todas las columnas en el procedimiento y listarlas todas en el controller y en la vista para que se ejecute correctamente, pero no estoy interesado en listar todas las columnas de la tabla.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, me alegra que hayas visto el recorrido, ayuda mucho :D Claro que podemos ayudarte, es simple hermano, coloca todo el código que crees conveniente para que la comunidad pueda reproducir tu escenario, en esta oportunidad, sólo podemos generar una tabla con 4 campos y un procedimiento almacenado cuyo nombre podemos definir. Edita la pregunta, agrega el controlador y los datos que le pasas

Comment: Por cierto, percibo que eres relativamente nuevo en ASP.net MVC, este workshop te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Espero lo disfrutes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el "explorador de modelos" => "Editar Importación de Función" cambié la opción "Devuelve una colección de" de Entidad que era donde lo tenía a "Complejo", y así me devuelve las columnas que deseo, sin traer el modelo completo de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya pasó más de 24 horas, puedes proceder a marcar la respuesta como aceptada, de tal manera colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Comment: Hay un check verde que sólo pueden verlo quienes han redactado la pregunta, marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor. Gracias por tu colaboración con la buena salud del sitio :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx, no conocía de eso, ya procedo con eso.

Comment: Con cariño hermano, eres nuevo en el sitio y estás en proceso de aprendizaje, gracias a ti por leer los comentarios en buen plan y permitir que usuarios con mayor experiencia (por no decir, viejos) colaboren con tu formación en SOes (StackOverflow en ESpañol)

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

- Los ViewBags, Los ViewData van en el mismo action, te darán mayor
  control de lo que ves.
- ¿En dónde defines `MarcaCLS`? ¿No se supone que es solamente `Marca`?

Procedimiento Almacenado:

```
SELECT IIDMARCA, NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION, BHABILITADO FROM Marca WHERE BHABILITADO = 1
```

Controlador:

```
using prototipo_03.Models;

namespace procedimientos_almacenados.Controllers
{
    public class MarcaController : Controller
    {
        BDPasajeEntities bd = new BDPasajeEntities();
        // GET: Marca
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //ListarMarcas();
            ViewBag.ListaMarca = ListaMarca();
            return View();
        }

        public List<Marca> ListarMarcas()
        {
            List<Marca> listaDeMarcas = new List<Marca>();

            using (bd)
            {
                var ListaMarca3 = bd.SP_LISTAR_MARCAS().ToList();
                foreach (var item in ListaMarca3)
                {
                    var asignar = new Marca
                    {
                        //Ojo con los nombres de tu clase
                        iidMarca = item.IIDMARCA,
                        nombreMarca = item.NOMBRE,
                        descripcionMarca = item.DESCRIPCION,
                        //Aqui viene el problema, falta especificar la propiedad 
                        bhabilitado = item.BHABILITADO 
                    };
                    listaDeMarcas.Add(asignar);
                }
                //Fin del foreach
            } //Fin del using
            return listaDeMarcas;
         } //Fin del método.
     }
 }
```

Comment: En unos tutoriales que encontré, se creaba una clase por cada tabla de la base de datos, en este caso tengo una tabla llamada Marca, y yo creo una clase llamada MarcaCLS y se trabajaba en base a ella.

Comment: La propiedad BHABILITADO ya probé agregándola dentro del foreach en el controller, sigue generando el error, también la agregué en la vista <td>@item.BHABILITADO</td> y persiste el problema, la agregué al procedimiento almacenado y se corrige, pero esa columna no es de mi interés que se muestre.

Comment: el procedure quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LISTAR_MARCAS
AS
BEGIN
SELECT IIDMARCA, 'NOMBRE', DESCRIPCION, BHABILITADO
FROM Marca
WHERE BHABILITADO = 1
END
```

pero no es mi inteción que se muestre la columna BHABILITADO, ella solo tiene la función de decirme si está activo o no ese registro.

Comment: coloca un breackpoint en el foreach del método ListarMarcas(), tómale un pantallazo y agrega esa información en la pregunta. El problema está en el "mismatch" (falta de correspondencia) entre el SP y la clase.

Comment: Si ya has realizado las sugerencias de la respuesta, ¿en qué parte se rompe?

Comment: si en el procedimiento hago la consulta SELECT IIDMARCA, NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION
FROM Marca
WHERE BHABILITADO = 1 en lugar de SELECT IIDMARCA, NOMBRE, DESCRIPCION, BHABILITADO
FROM Marca
WHERE BHABILITADO = 1 (solicitar la columna bhabilitado) me genera lo siguiente system.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'BDPasajeModel.Marca'. A member of the type, 'BHABILITADO', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name. Arriba también coloqué una imagen referente.

Comment: No estoy interesado en que se muestre esa columna(bhabilitado)

Comment: El error te dice "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'BDPasajeModel.Marca'. A member of the type, 'BHABILITADO', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name", la interpretación es simple "lo que traes de la base de datos NO corresponde a la clase que estás usando"

Comment: SI, el contenido del mensaje lo entendí, lo que no sé es como devolver la información que quiero(id, nombre, descripcion), quité la columna del sp, en mi vista la omití de la tabla<td>item.bhabilitado</td> y en el controller no asigno la propiedad(bhabilitado), por ende no sé como corregir eso.

Comment: fredyfx gracias por tu tiempo, ya pude resolver, gracias por la colaboración, a la orden cualquier consulta.